# PropertyGridForm.js Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: sitecore-forms

My form builder editor window is not loading and the spinner keeps on spinning and I'm getting this error in my console.
For this error I'm able find a [post regarding the same issue](https://codeandlearnspot.wordpress.com/2019/07/14/sitecore-forms-extensions-tds-sync-propertygridform-js-error/) but that is after adding Sitecore Form Extension and I haven't added that module.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/COhHu.png

Any help/solution will be appreciated!

Comment: Even though you have not installed Forms Extensions, can you try that solution once? If the FieldBindingsTokenDatasource in PropertyGridForm item?

Comment: FieldBindingsTokenDatasource is not there in PropertyGridForm item that's why I haven't tried that solution.